# using map API as offline in mobile application?

Tags: java, java-me, dictionary, bing-maps

I want to have an application in java, for mobile..
I must build the application offline,and the application must show user location.. So I want to show user location on the offline map, that I already saved in application package, I don't care about memory space, just use offline-map, to show current location of user,
what is the best applicable way to do this?

Comment: I've removed the Google Maps tag because the Terms of Service don't allow the use of their maps offline (that would involve a bulk download of the map tiles).

Comment: i want just one way to show current GPS location of user without internet connection, may be a graphic representation, shape file or any thing else, with C# also will help me..

Comment: i'm sure there is a way to do that, unfortunately no body tell me how, i searched more times with different ways but couldn't find some good thing, why no body answer me?!!

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps does not allow the map control to be used offline with the exception of the Windows Phone 8/8.1 map controls.